# WAV recorder function, need to change the format to int16 or int24

Tags: c#, audio, format, record, wav

```
public class Worker
{
    private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

        public void WavRecorder()
    {
        mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("recording, press Enter to stop and save ...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        mciSendString("save recsound result.wav", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
    }
```

this code records from my microphone and saves the recorded WAV file in the current directory of my project. However, the format of this WAV file is not what I want. It's not int. I need the format of the WAV file that is saved to be 'int 16' or 'int 24' format. Does anyone know how to save it in such format? or convert it to such format?

Comment: Have you set [lpstrAlgorithm or lpstrQuality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Comment: no, how can i do that?

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Media Control Interface (MCI)

Comment: in the documentation the code is in c++ but I need c#. Also, if you don't mind, would you tell me how to make sense of any documentation? Do I have to just keep reading until I understand a sentence in it? I don't even know what I'm looking for while reading

Comment: winmm.dll is an unmanaged library, so you'll need to [Pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm.mcisendstring) in order to make use of it in .NET. You should already be aware of this if you're using the interface. As far as the documentation goes, You wouldn't be the first to find MSDN documentation hard to understand. I can't really help you there. You might consider to using an existing wrapper such as [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

possibly this will work ... I do not have Window$ so cannot execute it myself

```
public void WavRecorder() {

    mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias capture", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("set capture time format ms bitspersample 16", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("set capture channels 1 samplespersec 8000", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("set capture alignment 1 bytespersec 8000", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("record capture", "", 0, 0);

    Console.WriteLine("recording, press Enter to stop and save ...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    mciSendString("stop capture", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("save capture \"" + result.wav + "\"", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("close capture", "", 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: actually my code says "8 bits per sample is not supported by FLAC!" so the WAV is not 16? it's 8? i think

Comment: Find the configuration setting which allows you to record using 16 bits ... avoid trying to convert a 8 bit WAV into 16 bits

Comment: what do you mean by configuration setting? is it something to do with msisendstring?

Comment: Actually I'm confused with the code you provided me. I don't quite understand it. Do I just add it to my function?

Comment: I added a link in above to same question ... initially just try adding   bitspersample 16

Comment: I'm not sure what  this line refers to>    error = mciSendString(command, _mciReturnData, 0, IntPtr.Zero);    what is 'error', what is '_mciReturnData'? and what is ' IntPtr.Zero'?

Comment: ignore that for now ... use this instead of the similar line your have :    mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound bitspersample 16", "", 0, 0);       make this your only change

Comment: I get the same error: 8 bits per sample is not supported by FLAC!
[HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsopm8izs7j36ej/WaveConverter.zip?dl=0) is my project

Comment: I use ubuntu linux, do not have a Windows machine

Comment: I have a question. There are so many things in this code that are not defined, and which I don't know how to define. So, please tell me what are the following? _mciReturnData, WaveAlignment, WaveBytesPerSec, WaveSamplesPerSec, WaveChannels, WaveBitsPerSample, channels, samplespersec. What are all of those variable types and what should they be assigned?

Comment: In my above answer at the end I say :  "try this"  ... well did you ?  that is the simplest attempt at a solution ... for now ignore all the rest

Comment: Yes I did, i still get the error saying: make sure your file is in 16 or 24 bit int form.